# ScadaBR send email SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, firewall, smtp-auth

I need to send an email with a software called ScadaBR (which is for industrial supervision). As my "SMTP host" I use the name of the company server that we use to send emails with port 25 because we don't use any authentication. However I can't connect to the server from the software, it gives me the error `"connection failed with the server"`.

The full error is:

> Failed to send email titled "ScadaBR test email" to "FRWLT@bost.com".
>   Message: "Mail server connection failed; nested exception is  javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp-eu.app.corp, port: 25; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10107: connect"

The email destination is `FRWLT@bost.com` and the server name is `smtp-eu.app.corp`.

I tried to use the gmail server but in the company where I work use some firewal seems to stop any kind of connection with the port 587 (the port that connects with the gmail server).
I have an positive answer when I try to ping the server and also I have a positive answer when I try the connection via "putty" with telnet.

Can anyone help me connecting to the SMTP server?